# Add the value from the cellbelow to the cell above

Tags: r

I guess this is an easy question, however I would appreciate help! I want to add a value to the cell above. Any suggestions?

```
 a <- c(0,"D",0,"E",0,"F")
 b <- c(0,"E",0,"F",0,"D")
 c <- cbind(a,b)
 c <- as.data.frame(c)
 c
 a b
 0 0
 D E
 0 0
 E F
 0 0
 F D

I want it to look like this:
 a b
 D0 E0
 D  E
 E0 F0
 E  F
 F0 D0
 F  D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that with a simple `for` loop:

```
a <- c(0,"D",0,"E",0,"F")
b <- c(0,"E",0,"F",0,"D")
c <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


for(row in seq(from=1, to=nrow(c), by=2)){

    c[row, ] <- paste0(c[row+1, ], c[row, ])
}

print(c)

#   a  b
#1 D0 E0
#2  D  E
#3 E0 F0
#4  E  F
#5 F0 D0
#6  F  D
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, we can use `lead` to paste values from next rows where the `row_number()` is odd

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_all(~ifelse(row_number() %% 2 == 1, paste0(lead(.), .), .)) 

#   a  b
#1 D0 E0
#2  D  E
#3 E0 F0
#4  E  F
#5 F0 D0
#6  F  D
```

**data**

Make sure you read data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
a <- c(0,"D",0,"E",0,"F")
b <- c(0,"E",0,"F",0,"D")
df <- data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Nice! How should I do to mutate a specific column, not all columns?

Comment: @raquel Use `mutate_at`. Select columns by position `df %>%
  mutate_at(1:2, ~ifelse(row_number() %% 2 == 1, paste0(lead(.), .), .))` or by name `df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(a,b), ~ifelse(row_number() %% 2 == 1, paste0(lead(.), .), .))`

Answer (score 1):

As with the other answers, I modified the `as.data.frame` call to have `stringsAsFactors = F`.

```
n_rows <- nrow(c)
c_changed <- c('a', 'b')

c[seq(1, n_rows, by = 2), c_changed] <- Map(paste0, c[seq(2, n_rows, by = 2), c_changed], c[seq(1, n_rows, by = 2), c_changed])

c

   a  b
1 D0 E0
2  D  E
3 E0 F0
4  E  F
5 F0 D0
6  F  D
```

Data:

```
a <- c(0,"D",0,"E",0,"F")
b <- c(0,"E",0,"F",0,"D")
c <- cbind(a,b)
c <- as.data.frame(c, stringsAsFactors = F)
```